# Error running Jest test from LitElement File (modules import)

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babel-jest, lit-element

When i try to run jest tests, the self written typescript files are working fine. But the LitElement files won't (Transpile) thats my guess.

I've cleared the cache,
I've created the babel.config.js file
And tried to add the modules to the transformIgnorePatterns.

Jest Error from test:

```
import { TemplateResult } from 'lit-html';
           ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

    > 1 | import { css, *CSSResult*, customElement, html, *LitElement* } from 'lit-element';
```

Jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    // Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test
    clearMocks: true,

    // Indicates whether the coverage information should be collected while executing the test
    collectCoverage: true,

    // An array of glob patterns indicating a set of files for which coverage information should be collected
    // collectCoverageFrom: null,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        '**/*.{js,jsx}',
        '!**/node_modules/**',
        '!**/vendor/**',
        '!**/bin/**'
    ],

    // An array of regexp pattern strings used to skip coverage collection
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/bin/'],

    // An object that configures minimum threshold enforcement for coverage results
    // coverageThreshold: null,
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            branches: 80,
            functions: 80,
            lines: 80,
            statements: -10
        }
    },

    // An array of file extensions your modules use
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'node'],

    roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],

    // The test environment that will be used for testing
    testEnvironment: 'node',

    // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all test paths, matched tests are skipped
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/bin/'],

    // A map from regular expressions to paths to transformers
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
        '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$':
            '<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules-transform'
    },

    // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all source file paths, matched files will skip transformation
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        '/node_modules/',
        '/node_modules/(?!CCSResult).+\\.js$',
        '/node_modules/(?!html).+\\.js$',
        '/node_modules/(?!css).+\\.js$',
        '/node_modules/(?!lit-element).+\\.js$',
        '/node_modules/(?!lit-html).+\\.js',
        '/node_modules/(?!lit-boilerplate).+\\.js'
    ],

    modulePaths: ['<rootDir>']
};
```

Hello.ts file

```
import { css, CSSResult, customElement, html, LitElement } from 'lit-element';
import { TemplateResult } from 'lit-html';

/**
 * App root component
 */
@customElement('example-hello')
export class Hello extends LitElement {
    static get styles(): CSSResult {
        return css`
            button {
                background-color: palevioletred;
                padding: 5px 8px;
                color: white;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        `;
    }

    /**
     * Render function
     */
    public render = (): TemplateResult => html`
        <button>Hello</button>
    `;

    demo: number = sum(20, 10);
}

export function sum(first: number, second: number): number {
    return first + second;
}

declare global {
    interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
        'example-hello': Hello;
    }
}
```

Babel configuration file:

```
// babel.config.js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                targets: {
                    node: 'current'
                }
            },
            '@babel/preset-typescript'
        ]
    ],
    plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript', { isTSX: true }],
        ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'],
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }]
    ]
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        /* Basic Options */
        "target": "es2018",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
        "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
        "lib": ["dom", "es2018"],                 /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
        "declaration": true,                      /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
        "sourceMap": true,                        /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
        "outDir": "./dist",                       /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
        "rootDir": "./src",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
        "noResolve": false,                       /* Do not add triple-slash references or module import targets to the list of compiled files. */
        "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts). */

        /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
        "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options below. */

        /* Additional Checks */
        "noUnusedLocals": true,                   /* Report errors on unused locals. */
        "noUnusedParameters": true,               /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
        "noImplicitReturns": true,                /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */

        /* Module Resolution Options */
        "moduleResolution": "node",               /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
        "baseUrl": "./",                          /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
        "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */

        /* Experimental Options */
        "experimentalDecorators": true            /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "!node_modules/@types",
        "package.json",
        "postcss.config.js",
        "src/assets",
        "dist",
        "webpack.config.js"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```

I expect to run Jest and that the test and passes.
(Typescript files without imports work and return passed.)

Comment: Are you using `babel-jest`? Can you share your babel configuration file?

Comment: Yes i do @Umbo I've added it above.
```

Comment: I forgot to ask you about the `tsconfig.json`, could you post that as well?

Comment: @Umbo here it is.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that in `transformIgnorePatterns` you're skipping the transformation of `lit-element` and `lit-html`. The error seems to occur in the `lit-element` package because of untranspiled es imports. Try not to ignore those packages and see what happens.

Comment: Any updates on these issue?